# What is the function of the script tag? Execution or referencing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am NOT asking where to put the `<script>` tag in HTML markup. My question is what is its function. Does it reference to a script so that all the functions of the script can be run later on or it executes the script and does no reference.

For example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body onresize="hello();">
        <div id="navigation_pane">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>CONTACTS</li>
                <li>JOIN</li>
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="testElement"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another version of the same markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onresize="hello();">
        <div id="navigation_pane">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>CONTACTS</li>
                <li>JOIN</li>
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="testElement"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, in the first case, where the tag is placed at the bottom of the script and when the page is resized, the function `hello()` is working correctly. So, in this case I assume the function of the tag to run as well as execute the script.

But in the second case, the function `hello()` is not running, so this leads to the conclusion that the `<script>` tag only executes a script, not references to it, and in this case, since the script executes before the page loads, it cannot reference the body.

So, what is the function of the tag? Execution or reference?

Just in case you are wondering, this is the script:

```
"use strict";
var navigationPane = document.getElementById("navigation_pane");
var height = navigationPane.clientHeight;

function hello(){
    document.getElementById("testElement").textContent = navigationPane.clientHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it reference to a script so that all the functions of the script can be run later on or it executes the script and does no reference.

It references a script, which causes the browser to execute it. This might alter the state of the environment (e.g. by creating global variables).

> But in the second case, the function hello() is not running, so this leads to the conclusion that the `<script>` tag only executes a script, not references to it, and in this case, since the script executes before the page loads, it cannot reference the body.

If a script errors before creating a global variable (`hello` in this case), then the variable won't exist when you try to access it later.

Answer (score 0):

(The terms `run` and `execute` are synonymous in this case, FYI)

A script tag serves as both a reference and an execution point for a script. The browser parses HTML procedurally, meaning it starts at the `html` tag, then parses the `head` tag, then the `body`, and so on. When the browser gets to a script tag, it stops, loads the `script` being referenced, executes it, and then continues down past the `script` tag parsing the rest of the document. A script can be both inline `<script>alert('hey!')</script>` and an *external* reference `<script src='...'>`.

A `<script />` tag is executed by the browser while the document is parsing the page's HTML. In the first case, the `<script />` tag is executed after the browser has parsed the majority of the page's HTML, which means that the `#testElement` now exists, and therefore can be found using `document.getElementById`, as most of the DOM has been built.

In the second case, the `script` tag is executed while the browser is parsing the `head` tag, which is *before* your `#testElement` comes into existence. Therefore, your script can't find the element, and fails.